# Magento product list not displaying on mobile homepage

Tags: php, html, css, magento, mobile

I'm working on a **Magento** web-shop where I should display some products on the home page, with a customised list.phtml.

The products **appear** the demanded way on **desktop**, but they **don't appear on mobile** and the *div containing them is not even a part of the html on mobile screen*.

It looks the following way:

```html
<h1 class="title-list-home">BESTSELLERS</h1>
<hr style="margin-bottom: 20px;" />
<p>{{Block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" is_homepage="1" category_id="213" template="catalog/product/list-home.phtml"}}</p>
<h3 style="font-size=16px; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 50px;"><a href="#">See more products...</a></h3>
```

What could go wrong, that the block's content on mobile is not getting injected at all to the homepage? The block is allowed in the permissions and once again it works perfectly on desktop.

Comment: First of all, dont use styles inline, it's horrible practice. Then we need see the output html from <p>´{{Block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" is_homepage="1" category_id="213" template="catalog/product/list-home.phtml"}}´</p>

Comment: @Apeiron Yeah, I'm gonna try to avoid them in future. It's a <div class="category-products"> with a <ul> of different products, but on mobile it just becomes an empty <p> tag.

Comment: That's strange... Are you loading any javascript?

Comment: @Apeiron I couldn't find any relevant JS that would be in control for <div class="category-products">. Maybe if you could add me to a chat room, I could show you the site and you could have a better vision over it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using the different themes for the desktop and mobile? The problem also can be in your theme (for example JS is changing the page content depending on screen resolution).

Comment: It's interesting, because the h1, hr and h3 all appears from the same cms->pages-> home source, but the p tags become totally empty when I refresh on mobile.

Comment: Try to check what will happen if you turn off JavaScript in the browser.

Comment: It's totally the same behaviour, I don't have an idea what might be responsible for it...

Comment: Have you checked the theme configuration? The custom work logic can be in the "catalog/product/list-home.phtml" and "catalog/product_list" files.

Comment: I have, the list-home seems to be all right and there is no file called product list. Maybe I can send you a url in chat if you want to have a better look at it.

Comment: It's http://www.winkwink.dk/, the Tilbud (Discount) and Bestsellers categories. Hope you ain't gonna lose the focus :)

Comment: You are using the different themes for desktop ('default/winkwink') and mobile ('default/mobile'). You can check the dessign setting in the admin (Admin > System > Configuration > General > Design > Themes). You should to check if these themes use the same 'catalog/product/list-home.phtml' file (it can be different per theme).

Comment: I've found the issue. The list-home.phtml was missing from the 'default/mobile' theme directory. Thanks for your help and patience! :)